# Как работает код?

Tags: java

```
public class Solution
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int s = 0;
        int k = 2;
        int i = 0;
        for(k--; k < 10; k++)
        {
            k += 2;
            if(k == 6)
            {
                continue;
            }
            s += k;
            i++;
        }
        System.out.println("s = " + s);
        System.out.println("k = " + k);
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
    }
}
```

Выше заданная программа выдает результаты s = 12, k = 10, i = 2, но понять ее логику, тоесть как она работает (именно в цикле) не могу.

Comment: Вы уверены, что I равно на выходе 2? Я не вижу, где в коде эта переменная изменяется.

Comment: В IntelliJ IDEA проверял. Выдает именно 2.

Comment: Программа проверяется запуском ее на выполнение, хотя и без ее выполнения, как говорится, невооруженным взглядом видно, что I нигде не изменяется.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

На самом деле вывод будет следующим

```
s = 12
k = 10
i = 0
```

Переменная `i`  нигде в коде после инициализации не меняется.

Что касается других двух переменных, то легко подсчитать "на пальцах", чему они будут равны.

Итак после инициализации `k` значением 2 имеем

```
    for(k--; k < 10; k++)
    {
        k += 2
```

После `k--` `k` стало равным 1. Далее внутри тела цикла она увеличивается на 2

```
        k += 2;
```

и после выхода из тела цикла она увеличивается на 1

```
    for(k--; k < 10; k++)
                    ^^^^
```

Соответственно `k` последовательно получает следующие значения  перед проверкой условия цикла

1, 4, 7, 10

Поле чего цикл завершается

Однако в теле цикла переменная `k` будет иметь следующие значения

3, 6, 9

Соответственно переменная `s` будет равна сумме 3 + 9 = 12, так как значение k равное 6 пропускается

```
        if(k == 6)
        {
            continue;
            ^^^^^^^^
        }
        s += k;
```

**EDIT**: Так как с первой попытки вам не удалось набрать правильный исходный код в вашем вопросе, и сейчас он отличается от того, что было первоначально, то имеет место следующее.

Произошло только одно изменение: добавлено в цикл предложение, которое меняет значение переменной **i**

```
    for(k--; k < 10; k++)
    {
        k += 2;
        if(k == 6)
        {
            continue;
        }
        s += k;
        i++;
        ^^^^^
    }
```

Так как, как было показано выше, тело цикло будет выполнено три раза для значений `k` соответственно равных 3, 6, 9 и при значении `k` равным 6  выполнение тела цикла прерывается из-за предложения `contine`, то данное предложение

```
        i++;
```

будет выполнено всего два раза. В результате конечным значением переменной `i` будет 2.

Comment: Извиняюсь. Моя ошибка. В цикле должно быть i++ .

Comment: @Владимир В таком случае I также не может быть равно 2 после завершения программы. Вообщем, ничего сложного или не понятного здесь нет.

Comment: Понял. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Переменная `s` каждую итерацию, если `k` не равно `6` прибавляет саму себя к переменной `k`
В начале каждой итерации переменная `k` увеличивается на `2`
Итерация продолжается до тех пор, пока `k` меньше `10`

```
Итог итерации 1: s = 0 + 2 - 1 + 2 = 3, k = 2 - 1 + 2 + 1 = 4, i = 0
Итог итерации 2: s = 3, k = 4 + 2 + 1 = 7, i = 0 | пропуск итерации
Итог итерации 3: s = 3 + 9 = 12, k = 7 + 2 + 1 = 10, i = 0
```